# Problems deploying a WinForms app that uses Microsoft ReportViewer

Tags: deployment, .net-4.0, installation, clickonce, reportviewer

I have published a WinForms application from Visual Studio 2010. It uses .NET 4.0. in the prerequisite dialog in Publish pane I selected .NET 4.0 Client Profile and Windows Installer 3.0. After publishing application to disk, I migrated it to client's computer which first installed .NET Client Profile and after reboot it gave following error message:

> Unable to Install or run application. The application requires that assembly, `Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common` version 10.0.0 in global assembly cache first.

After this message the installation process exits. I'm using .NET's report in my project (not Crystal Reports).

Comment: i just changed its status from prerequisite to include in application files popup and it is working now on client's computer. how is that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**You have to deploy the ReportViewer controls separately.**

Check here on MSDN for more information: [Deploying Reports and ReportViewer Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251723.aspx)

> The ReportViewer control redistributable is a self-extracting file named ReportViewer.exe that includes an .msi and other files. You can find ReportViewer.exe at the following location:
>
> ```
> %PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\ReportViewer\ReportViewer.exe
> ```
>
> You can also [download it from the Microsoft Download Center](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=a941c6b2-64dd-4d03-9ca7-4017a0d164fd&displaylang=en).
>
> [ . . . ]
>
> The type of control you are using
>   determines where ReportViewer.exe
>   should be run.
>
> - For ASP.NET applications, run
>     ReportViewer.exe on the Web server
>     that hosts your application. This must
>     be done by a server administrator.
> - For Windows Forms applications,
>     include the controls as an application
>     prerequisite so that they are
>     installed automatically with your
>     application. You can use the
>     bootstrapping application to automate
>     this step:
>
>   - Open the project properties page.
>   - Click **Publish**, and then click
>       **Prerequisites**.
>   - Select **Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
>       Report Viewer**, and then click **OK**.
>   - Publish the application.
>
> During application installation, a
>   check is performed on the local
>   computer to see if ReportViewer is
>   already installed. If it is not
>   installed, the Setup program will
>   install it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is probably a new VS2012 feature, but you now can [deploy Report Viewer (and the SQL Server CLR Types) with Forms / WPF click once installations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251723.aspx).

> 1. Open the project properties page.
> 2. Click the Publish tab, and then click the Prerequisites button.
> 3. Select Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Report Viewer, and SQL Server
>      CLR Types then click OK.
> 4. Make sure that the Download prerequisites from the component
>      vendor’s website option is checked. This is the only supported
>      option. Then, click OK.
> 5. Click the Options button.
> 6. In the Deployment tab, specify a deployment Web page and select the
>      Automatically generate deployment web page after ever publish
>      checkbox.
> 7. Click OK and publish the application.

Answer (score 0):

look at this: [Running ReportViewer.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251723%28VS.80%29.aspx)

both we are gave you same link. it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Download and install Microsoft Report Viewer 2012 Runtime CTP from following url...

http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=27230

I had same problem but it solved after install the above...

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for months, one machine cat v.11 installed (manually by adding some components) and another had v.10 (from the ms framework itself), when I did the publish from my machine, it gave the error.

here is how I fixed it,

In Nuget, there are 2 packages, 

Microsoft.ReportViewer.Windows (Microsoft.ReportViewer runtime 2012) and

ReportViewer.Common 10.0

I installed them both, now its working quite all right

Comment: were you getting the CLR Type for SQL SERVER error?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open project properties Alt+Enter.
2. Click on publish tab.
3. Click on prerequisites select Microsoft visual studio report viewer.

visit this website for more detail
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251723.aspx