# Windows Forms Application GAC Warning

Tags: .net, winforms, gac

After publishing windows forms application the following warning appears. What should I do ?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems deploying a WinForms app that uses Microsoft ReportViewer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230858/problems-deploying-a-winforms-app-that-uses-microsoft-reportviewer). The link to the possible duplicate is about another assembly but the answer will apply tp your situation as well.

Comment: That assembly is a never-ending source of trouble.  You could start by fixing your own machine first, remove that assembly from the your GAC.  It doesn't belong there.  That's probably going to break *some* program, the one that put it there.  Send a nastygram to the owner of that program.